# How to clear part of canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

[Here is an example!](http://jsbin.com/acuyun/2/edit)

I am trying to reset the green arc inside `drawValueArc()` so that each time you click the change button, the green arc is removed and redrawn. How can I remove it without removing the entire canvas? Also, as an aside, I have noticed that `Math.random() * 405 * Math.PI / 180` doesn't actually always result in an arc that fits inside the gray arc, sometimes it is larger than the gray arc, why is this?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var cx = 150;
var cy = 150;
var startRadians = 135 * Math.PI / 180;
var endRadians = 405 * Math.PI / 180;

//main arc
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx, cy, 58, startRadians, endRadians, false);
ctx.strokeStyle="rgb(220,220,220)";
ctx.lineWidth = 38;
ctx.stroke();

$('#setRandomValue').click(function(){
  drawValueArc(Math.random() * 405 * Math.PI / 180);
});


function drawValueArc(val){
  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, 58, startRadians, val, false);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
  ctx.lineWidth = 38;
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: This may be overkill, but you could consider trying out EaselJS http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS or some other canvas library. This will give really great control of each element that is being drawn. And a lot of the simple shapes/polygons are already built out and easy to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Drawing past boundary

The problem you are facing is in first instance the fact you are drawing before and after a 0-degree on the circle. This can be complicated to handle as you need to split in two draws: one for the part up to 0 (360) and one 0 to the remaining part.

There is a simple trick you can use to make this easier to deal with and that is to deal with all angles from 0 and use an offset when you draw.

**Demo using redraw base** (I moved it to jsfiddle as jsbin did not work for me):

<kbd>**http://jsfiddle.net/3dGLR/**</kbd>

**Demo using off-screen canvas**

<kbd>**http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Dg9Jj/**</kbd>

First, some optimizations and settings for the offset:

```
var startRadians = 0;        //just deal with angles
var endRadians = 300;
var deg2rad = Math.PI / 180; //pre-calculate this to save some cpu cycles
var offset = 122;            //adjust this to modify rotation
```

We will now let the main function, `drawArc()` do all calculations for us so we can focus on the numbers - here we also offset the values:

```
function drawArc(color, start, end) {
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.arc(cx, cy, 58,
        (startRadians + offset) * deg2rad,
        (end + offset) * deg2rad, false);

    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = 38;
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

### Clearing the previous arc

There are several techniques to clear the previous drawn arc:

1. You can draw the base arc to an off-screen canvas and use `drawImage()` to erase the old.
2. You can do as in the following example, just re-draw it with the base color
3. As with 2. but subtracting the green arc and draw the base color from the end of the green arc to the end of the base arc.
4. clearing the whole canvas with `fillRect` or `clearRect`.

1 and 3 are the fastest, while 4 is the slowest.

With out re-factored function (`drawArc`) it's as easy as this:

```
function drawValueArc(val) {
    drawArc("rgb(220,220,220)", startRadians, endRadians);
    drawArc("green", startRadians, val);
}
```

As everything now is 0-based concerning start we really don't need to give any other argument than 0 to the `drawArc` instead of `startRadians`. Use the new offset to offset the start position and adjust the `endRadians` to where you want it to stop.

As you can see in the demo, using this technique keeps everything in check without the need to draw in split.

Tip: if you notice green artifacts on the edges: this is due to anti-alias. Simply reduce the line width for the green color by 2 pixels (see demo 2, off-screen canvas).

Comment: I have some shadows and markers that should go in the final version of this, like so: http://jsbin.com/oqupis/4/edit I was thinking about putting these in another canvas ontop of the one with the green changing value. Do you think this is a good idea, or should I re-draw them on the same canvas each time?? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @sherlock IMO I would draw all the static parts to the bottom layer and only draw the green bar at the top layer. This way it's less to maintain. But also, there isn't really need for a second layer in this case - you can just redraw the base for the gauge. Performance should be good. Don't forget to up-vote/accept answer if it was useful. ;)

Comment: Here is the (mostly) final product if you want to check it out. And if you have any tips, they would be appreciated. Thanks again. http://jsfiddle.net/watson/cUSBQ/6/

Comment: @sherlock That looks pretty neat in fact. The only suggestion I can give here is to replace setInterval with requestAnimationFrame. That will make the animation super-smooth. But looks great as it is as well. Good work!

Comment: Thats a good tip, but I can't seem to get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/watson/cUSBQ/8/ ?

Comment: @sherlock open it as a new question and we can take it from there :)

Comment: Here you go ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497248/requestanimationframe-seems-slow-cancelanimationframe-not-working