# requestAnimationFrame seems slow, cancelAnimationFrame not working

Tags: javascript, canvas

[This is what I'm working on.](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/cUSBQ/9/) If you scroll to JS line 63 you will see the function I am having difficulty with. I am trying to replace my setInterval code (in comments) with requestAnimationFrame. But the animation seems to be going rather slowly, also,  it doesn't ever stop!! [Here is a working version with setInterval](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/cUSBQ/10/).

Relevant JS:

```
function setGauge(val){
    var time = 350;
    time = time / (Math.abs(val - preVal));

    if (val > preVal) {
        function getHigher(){
           if (preVal == val)
                cancelAnimationFrame(animate);
            preVal++;
            drawValueArc(preVal);
            var animate = requestAnimationFrame(getHigher);
        }
        getHigher();
        /*
        var animate = setInterval(function(){
            if (preVal == val)
                clearInterval(animate);
            preVal++;
            drawValueArc(preVal);  
        }, time);
        */
    } else if (val < preVal) {
        function getLower(){
           if (preVal == val)
                cancelAnimationFrame(animate2);
            preVal--;
            drawValueArc(preVal);  
            var animate2 = requestAnimationFrame(getLower);
        }
        getLower();
        /*
        var animate2 = setInterval(function(){
            if (preVal == val)
                clearInterval(animate2);
            preVal--;
            drawValueArc(preVal);  
        }, time);
        */
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified the code just slightly, you where almost there.

The `animate` and `animate2` isn't really needed as we don't cancel the requestAnimationFrame (rAF) but merely check if the condition for it to run is there:

```
function setGauge(val) {
    var time = 350;
    time = time / (Math.abs(val - preVal));

    if (val > preVal) {
        function getHigher() {
            preVal++;
            drawValueArc(preVal);

            //if still less then rAF again
            if (preVal < val) requestAnimationFrame(getHigher);
        }
        getHigher();

    } else if (val < preVal) {
        function getLower() {
            preVal--;
            drawValueArc(preVal);

            //if still more then rAF again
            if (preVal > val) requestAnimationFrame(getLower);
        }
        getLower();

     //...
}
```

See modified fiddle here (link seem to:

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/cUSBQ/11/</strike>

Comment: @artur99 huh.. that's strange. thanks, seem to be deleted for some reason - not sure I can do anything about it.