# cancelAnimationFrame(myAnim) not stopping animation in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am creating an animation and setting it to a variable

```
myAnim = requestAnimFrame(duckHunt);
```

I want to stop it using `cancelAnimationFrame(myAnim);`

It works in FF and Chrome in IE9 I get the error

```
SCRIPT5009 'cancelAnimationFrame' is undefined
```

is this a know issue? I am at the limits of my understanding, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue. Rather than cancelling the animation frame I added a conditional statement.
The event I wanted to stop the animation simply set the condition to false.

```
if(animate){requestAnimFrame(duckHunt);}
$(document).on('click',$button, function(e){
    animate=false;
}
```

I found the solution  reading the following post.

[requestAnimationFrame seems slow, cancelAnimationFrame not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497248/requestanimationframe-seems-slow-cancelanimationframe-not-working)

Comment: Good idea, most video games do something similar for pause functionality.